# $|(0,1)| = |\mathbb R|$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

For this problem in proving that the cardinality of $(0,1)$ is equal to that of the set of real numbers, would I just prove that $(0,1)$ is uncountable, and then use the theorem that the subset of an uncountable set is uncountable, by saying $(0,1) \subset ℝ$, and since $(0,1)$ is uncountable, than $ℝ$ must be uncountable, and therefore $|(0,1)| = |ℝ|$?

Comment: $\in\ne\subset$!

Answer (score 3):

Just because two sets are both uncountable does not imply that they have the same cardinality. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ and $P(\mathbb{R})$ are both uncountable, but the cardinality of $P(\mathbb{R})$ is strictly greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$.

For your problem, I would try to construct a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following bijection: $ f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R},$  $ f(x) = \frac{x-\frac{1}{2}}{x(x-1)} $.

This will map $0 \rightarrow -\infty, \frac{1}{2} \rightarrow 0, 1 \rightarrow \infty$, and from the obvious continuity of the function, you could use the intermediate value theorem for the proof of bijection.

Thus in **this** case, both sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: How would I implement the mean value theorem?

Comment: I think @EZSlayer means the Intermediate Value Theorem. Since $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to0$ and $f(x)\to-\infty$ as $x\to1$ (and since $f$ is continuous), we have by the IVT that $f$ is surjective. Using $f'<0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ we have that $f$ is (strictly decreasing and hence) also injective.

Comment: Thanks, @sranthrop. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No, because "uncountable" just means "bigger than countable."  There are lots of different uncountable cardinalities.

You need to construct an explicit bijection between (0, 1) and $\mathbb{R}$, or I guess you could construct injective maps in both directions and apply Cantor–Schroeder–Bernstein.

Answer (score 0):

Bad argument. Works only if Continuum Hypothesis is true.